# C ++: Check if the order of parentheses and brackets in a string is balanced using structure

Tags: c++, struct, stack

I need to verify that the expression is balanced, it has exactly the same number of parentheses and that the order is correct for square brackets and keys opening and closing, for example "{[(()]}". However, I need a struct for my stack, but I don't know how to do this. Could you help me? This code is working, but I need to use a struct instead of using a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool checkExpress(string str){
    int i;
    stack <char> st;

    if(str.length() % 2 != 0) return false;

    for(auto ch : str){

        if (ch == '('  ch == '[') {
            st.push(ch);
        } else if(ch == ')') {
            if(st.empty()  st.top() != '(') return false;
            st.pop();
        } else if(ch == ']') {
            if(st.empty() || st.top() != '[') return false;
            st.pop();
        } 
    }

    return true;
}


int main(){
    string a = "(([[]]))";

    if(checkExpress(a)) cout << "The expression is well constructed.";
    else cout << "The expression is not well constructed.";

    return 0;
}
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool checkExpress(string str){
    int i;
    stack <char> st;

    if(str.length() % 2 != 0) return false;

    for(char ch : str){
    if (ch == '(' || ch == '[') {
    st.push(ch);
    continue;
    }
    if (st.empty())
      return false;
    char top = st.top();
    st.pop();

    if (top == '(' && ch==')')
      continue; // we good
    if (top == '[' && ch==']')
      continue; // we good

    return false; // invalid character, or bad match
}
    return true;
}


int main(){
    string a = "(([[]]))";

    if(checkExpress(a)) cout << "The expression is well constructed.";
    else cout << "The expression is not well constructed.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem more clearly? What do you need the struct for and what is the issue with the code at the moment?

Comment: Why do you need a struct, when the current code is already working?

Comment: This is what stacks were made for. You will not improve the program by using a struct.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using linked list

```
struct Node { 
    char data; 
    struct Node* next; 
};
```

Then you can add if next one is one of "{[(" delete on "}])"

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like an exercise I'll not put code here and instead attempt to describe a thought process that might help you.

The conditions for a input string to be valid are that every parenthesis/bracket must have a corresponding closing character AND the order must match. You can check both conditions while reading the input string using a **helper stack** (any data structure that allows you do add and remove elements at the top is OK, therefore a stack is the natural choice).

- Read the input string and everytime you find an opening parenthesis/brackets you add it to the stack. You will only add the opening characters to the stack.
- Each time you encounter a closing character you should try to remove the character at the top of the stack

  - But only if it is the corresponding opening character of the closing character you are currently reading from the input string. If it is not then the order is wrong and the input string is not valid. If the stack is empty when you read a closing character then it means you have more closing characters than opening characters
  - If you finish reading the input string and the stack is empty then the input string is valid, otherwise it means you are missing some closing character (if the stack is not empty when you finishing reading the input string)

---

Note that if your input is a stack instead of a string, it does not change what you need to do. However, in that case you would be reading everything backwards, since with a stack you only access the element at the top. In that case, you can change the process to add closing characters to the **helper stack** instead. That is, now when you read your input stack whenever you find a closing character you add it to the **helper stack** and whenever you find an opening character you try to remove the corresponding closing character from the **helper stack**.